# How to determine which exceptions "x[]" might throw?

Tags: c#, exception, square-bracket

C# reference for square brackets says: Square brackets [] are used for arrays, indexers, and attributes. They can also be used with pointers. (It also says, for arrays) An exception is thrown if an array index is out of range.

So when you're using square brackets on something other than an array, how do you know what exceptions might be thrown?

For a Dictionary (for example) if you use accessor methods such as [Dictionary.TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) you can easily look up the exceptions that the method may throw, but the [C# reference for square brackets []](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3hd7ste.aspx) only says it may throw an exception for index out of range on arrays.

*So if you want to use the square brackets for some data type, where can you lookup which exceptions might be thrown for that data type?*

I tried accessing a nonexistent member of a Dictionary, just to see what happens, and I got KeyNotFoundException. I know you can also get NullReferenceException.  Where is this documented?  And what's the complete list?

Comment: why do you need a list? Would a generic `catch (Exception ex)` not work?

Comment: @DiskJunky, catching the generic Exception is a worst practice (except at the very top level when you might log it and still eject).

Comment: @pst agreed, also as it can be overloaded you can implement your own indexing implementation and throw whatever the hell you like :)

Comment: @AnthonyPegram in general I agree but in the case where you don't know the exception in advance, you're not left with many options apart from catching `Exception` or deliberately breaking it to see what execption is thrown - documentation non-withstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's documented with each implementation.  There's not an exhaustive list as the operator can be overloaded, so thoeretically any exception could be thrown.  The operator is typically documented as an `Item` property.

Here's some documentation on specific uses:

[Dictionary.Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx)

[Array.Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494734.aspx)

However, you should not need an exhaustive list on what *could* be thrown.  Exceptions are typically caught for one of two reasons:  either you want to *do* something about it (like the days before `TryParse` when catching an exception was the simplest way to catch a bad date format) or you just want to note that an exception occured and log it, in which case you typically rethow the actual exception.

Catching specific exceptions is good for the former case. For example if you catch a `NullReferenceException` it's typically to re-throw a different exception that indicates *which* reference is null (since this is not part of the stock `NullReferenceException)`.

In the latter case, Catching a generic `Exception` is fine if you just want to log and re-throw since there's likely nothing else you can do about it.

Comment: Thanks - I don't actually want to know what *could* be thrown for the sake of knowing everything.  I just want to know for the sake of knowing what's valid, so I can then imagine whether or not I want to handle it.  Case and point:  In my question, I said the Dictionary could throw NullReferenceException, but as it turns out, when you look under the Item properties, it actually can throw ArgumentNullException.  So if I write code to catch the NullReferenceException, I think I'm covering my tracks, but I'm actually foolishly writing garbage code.

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey - well, "garbage" is strong.  If you just catch `NullReferenceException` and it throws an `ArgumentNullException`, all that will happen is the exception will be caught higher up the stack, either by your code or by the framework code.

Comment: @D Stanley point is, without looking up the actual exception that might be thrown, I'm prone to write code, thinking I'm catching an exception that I'm not catching. Then when I'm debugging it, I'll see it threw "Null" exception but it didn't catch "Null" exception but the code says to catch "Null" until I spin around in circles and finally figure out there's more than one different type of "Null" exception.  Yup, that would be garbage code.  Worse than garbage.  I'm glad to have the answer to this question now, so I won't make that mistake, and I can search for places I've already made it.

Answer (score 4):

When the [[] Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3hd7ste.aspx) is applied to a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> or List<T>, it invokes the instance's [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx). An indexer is a special property with parameters and is typically called `Item`.

- [Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Item Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx)
  ArgumentNullException – *key* is `null`.
  KeyNotFoundException – The property is retrieved and *key* does not exist in the collection.
- [List<T>.Item Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc.aspx)
  ArgumentOutOfRangeException – *index* is less than 0 -or- *index* is equal to or greater than *Count*.
- ...

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, square brackets essentially let you access an indexed property - so whatever error is mentioned in the property indexer of the object you are using.

For arrays, it may be index out of range, for DataRow, it may be column not found and so on.

Answer (score 1):

When used to access an array, it can throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

When used for an attribue it can't throw any exception at all, as any error would be at compile time.

When used to access an indexer, it can throw any exception. The indexer can be implemented any way you want, and throw any exception it likes.